How can I get an enemy (rigidbody2d) that collides with my Player (characterbody2d) to kill my player?
I am using GDScript. I figured out how to get an enemy to follow my player, but i am stuck on how to kill my player when they collide. enemy script
player script
I know that i need an area2d for it to start working but i cant figure it out. Anybody got any helps or links to videos that could help maybe?
I followed a tutorial by "The ErrorDev" https://youtu.be/2IAMuYEZxJA?si=pRWMIA_oDs3ZRGY-
but it didn't work.
